# MySQL get from where count in another table is lower

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write a single mySQL statement to only return items (books) that haven't been rented. The the moment I have this but I know it's not right:

```
SELECT books.copies 
FROM books 
WHERE books.copies > (SELECT rentals.book_id, COUNT(rentals.book_id) As CountRentals 
                        FROM rentals 
                        WHERE rentals.book_id = books.id )
```

Comment: When a book is returned from being rented is it deleted from the `rentals` table?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `left join` to get all that have no entries in `rentals` table

```
SELECT b.copies 
FROM books b
LEFT OUTER JOIN rentals r ON r.book_id = b.id
WHERE r.book_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This query would first get the book_id and the number of copies rented and then joins with the books table to see if the number of copies are greater than the rented copies, and prints all such books and the available number of copies.

```
SELECT 
    b.id, b.copies - r.rentalCount
FROM 
    books b
    JOIN (
           SELECT book_id, count(*) rentalCount) 
           FROM rentals 
           GROUP BY book_id
         ) as r
    ON b.book_id = r.book_id
WHERE 
    b.copies > r.rentalCount
```